# OpenCV window in fullscreen and without any borders

Tags: c++, c, windows, opencv

In OpenCV when displaying an image with:

```
cvSetWindowProperty("displayCVWindow", CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, 
CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
```

There is a small border around the full screened window if anyone ever noticed. Is there a way to get a rid of this?

Screenshot showing border of window when in full screen mode. **Note**: the screenshot was cropped to show only top-left corner

[image: Screenshot showing border of window when in full screen mode. **Note**: the screenshot was cropped to show only top-left corner]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6512315/176769

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display an image in full screen borderless window in openCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512094/how-to-display-an-image-in-full-screen-borderless-window-in-opencv)

Comment: I tried your suggestion in that post but it doesnt get rid of the thin window border when in full screen mode.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot that shows this border?

Comment: I have included a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OpenCV does not provide this capability**.

If you want to have the image in fullscreen mode or floating around without window/borders you will have 2 choices:

- [Hack the window created by OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6512315/176769);
- [Create the window yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3541843/176769) using native API calls.

If you decide to hack the window, you may [try this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6512315/176769) and replace the `SetWindowLong()` call for:

```
SetWindowLong(win_handle, GWL_STYLE, 0;
```

If that doesn't work, you'll have to dig a little deeper into window creation on Windows.

Comment: Your suggestion: `SetWindowLong(win_handle, GWL_STYLE, 0)` almost works. The border on the right and bottom parts of the screen have now gone. There is still a very thin border on the left and top. Is it something to do with window position, you think? I tried  `SetWindowPos(win_handle, HWND_NOTOPMOST, x, y, w, h, flags);`, but it didnt help

Comment: Well, this approach seems very limited. It's best to create a window from scratch. Another approach is to [create a frameless OpenGL window as demonstrated here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052940/how-to-make-an-opengl-rendering-context-with-transparent-background), and then send your image to the GPU for display.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is actually not the presence of a border, but the window's background showing through for some reason. From what I understand, OpenCV's namedWindow actually creates a two windows, one inside the other. The "white lines" are actually the grey background of the parent window. The fix I used was to change the background colour to the colour of the Mat I was displaying through the Windows API.

Here's the code I used to fix it:

```
cv::namedWindow("mainWin", WINDOW_NORMAL);//create new window
cv::setWindowProperty("mainWin",CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);//set fullscreen property
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0, L"mainWin");//get window through Windows API
SetClassLongPtr(hwnd, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG) CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0)));//set window background to black; you can change the colour in the RGB()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and found it annoying, so I make a small function which just creates a "frame" of whatever colour you like and puts the image in there.  Unfortunately, since I counldn't find a reliable cross-platform way to get display-sizes, you have to pass them yourself.   Here's the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


_FULL_FRAMES = {}


def show_fullscreen(image, background_colour = None, window_name='window', display_number = 0, display_sizes=None):
    """
    Draw a fullscreen image.

    :param image: The image to show.
        If integer, it will be assumed to be in range [0..255]
        If float, it will be assumed to be in range [0, 1]
    :param background_colour: The background colour, as a BGR tuple.
    :param window_name: Name of the window (can be used to draw multiple fullscreen windows)
    :param display_number: Which monitor to display to.
    :param display_sizes: Size of displays (needed only if adding a background colour)
    """
    if image.dtype=='float':
        image = (image*255.999).astype(np.uint8)
    else:
        image = image.astype(np.uint8, copy=False)
    if image.ndim==2:
        image = image[:, :, None]

    assert display_number in (0, 1), 'Only 2 displays supported for now.'
    if window_name not in _FULL_FRAMES:
        cv2.namedWindow(window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
        if display_number == 1:
            assert display_sizes is not None
            first_display_size = display_sizes[0]
            cv2.moveWindow(window_name, *first_display_size)
        cv2.setWindowProperty(window_name,cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
        if background_colour is not None:
            background_colour = np.array(background_colour)
            if background_colour.dtype=='int':
                background_colour = background_colour.astype(np.uint8)
            else:
                background_colour = (background_colour*255.999).astype(np.uint8)
            assert display_sizes is not None, "Unfortunately, if you want to specify background color you need to specify display sizes."
            pic_display_size = display_sizes[display_number]
            aspect_ratio = pic_display_size[1]/float(pic_display_size[0])  # (hori/vert)
            frame_size_x = int(max(image.shape[0]/aspect_ratio, image.shape[1]))
            frame_size_y = int(max(image.shape[1]*aspect_ratio, image.shape[0]))
            _FULL_FRAMES[window_name] = np.zeros((frame_size_y, frame_size_x, 3), dtype=np.uint8) + background_colour
        else:
            _FULL_FRAMES[window_name] = None

    if _FULL_FRAMES[window_name] is not None:
        frame = _FULL_FRAMES[window_name]
        start_y, start_x = (frame.shape[0] - image.shape[0])//2, (frame.shape[1] - image.shape[1])//2
        frame[start_y: start_y+image.shape[0], start_x:start_x+image.shape[1]] = image
        display_img = frame
    else:
        display_img = image

    cv2.imshow(window_name, display_img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for t in np.linspace(0, 10, 1000):
        im = np.sin(-4*t+np.sin(t/4.)*sum(xi**2 for xi in np.meshgrid(*[np.linspace(-20, 20, 480)]*2)))*.5+.5
        show_fullscreen(im, background_colour=(0, 0, 0), display_sizes=[(1440, 900), (1920, 1080)], display_number=0)  #
        # show_fullscreen(im, background_colour=None, display_number=0)
```

Comment: For Python use:
`cv2.namedWindow(name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty(name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.imshow(name, frame)`