# Solution to OpenCV Fullyscreen Border

Tags: python, opencv

I am using a digital micromirror device in lab and need control of each of its individual mirrors. I can control it over HDMI by treating it at a second monitor. However, opencv puts a 1px wide white border around all images it displays:
[OpenCV window in fullscreen and without any borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446733/opencv-window-in-fullscreen-and-without-any-borders)

I was wondering if people you recommend an alternative to opencv that will allow me to display numpy arrays as full-screen borderless images. Alternatively, if someone could provide a fix to this opencv border problem that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of frame rate do you need? You could save your image (like as test.png) and then open that image in a full screen viewer. When you rewrite 'test.png' the image in the full screen image viewer will update. This would work for ~1 fps.

Comment: This is a good idea for debugging, I will try it out. However, for the application I am doing I need a higher framerate ~10-20 fps.