# how can I create a full screen without a border in opencv c ++?

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to run an evaluation in full screen. the monitor has a resolution of 1920x1080. The image that is to be displayed also has a resolution of 1920x1080.
I use the following code to represent this. I use c ++ and windows 10.

```
    cv::namedWindow("image", cv::WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN);
    cv::setWindowProperty("image", cv::WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv::WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);

    while (1)
    {
        cv::Mat img = cv::Mat::zeros(1080, 1920, CV_8UC3);
        cv::imshow("image", img);
        cv::waitKey(1);
    }
```

the image is displayed on the full screen.
what bothers me and where I can't find a solution is a border the opencv itself draws. the fullscreen picture has a resolution of 1919x1079. because the 0th row and 0th row (whole top and very left) cannot be edited and are gray.
Is there a solution for this?

So the coordinate (0/0) in the cv :: Mat is on the monitor in the full screen (1/1)

A section of the top right corner:

[image]

the whole picture:
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by saying `border`? can be better showing with visualization

Comment: I added that it is the gray border on the left side and on the upper edge ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV window in fullscreen and without any borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446733/opencv-window-in-fullscreen-and-without-any-borders)